# Display image in mvc 5

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a MVC application which requires, displaying the image on hovering the mouse in a label, which displays the image name .

Can anyone suggest how to achieve the same.

Thanks

Comment: MVC is not enough to describe your technology. It can be AngularJS, ASP.NET etc... Please, precise your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the label ,use a jquery event when mouse over the label it shows the image(models are one way)